# Mixed up column order, DBI::dbWriteTable used in R for BigQuery

Tags: r, google-bigquery, dbi

When executing the below code in R to create new table,
order of columns is mixed up for the table created within BigQuery.

Code:

```
library(DBI)
    
con <- dbConnect(
      bigrquery::bigquery(),
      project = "project_name",
      dataset = "dataset_name",
      billing = billing
    )


DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = con,
                  name = "table_name",
                  value = dataframe
                  )
```

Expected Output:

```
model Seg1 Seg2 Seg3 max
MDE12, 1, 7, 2, 7
KDV02, 3, 8, 3, 8
LKD21, 0, 9, 1, 9
```

Actual Output:

```
max Seg3 Seg1 model Seg2
7, 2, 1, MDE12, 7
8, 3, 2, KDV02, 8
9, 1, 0, LKD21, 9
```

Please help me wise man of this planet earth.

Thanks ahead
:)

Answer (score 1):

The function `bigrquery::dbWriteTable` does not have an argument to specify column order. However, the comment on this post

[Maintain column order when uploading an R data frame to Big Query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62331331/188963)

gives a solution for using `bigrquery` methods. I've tested it and it "works."

The comment:

> Have you tried providing a list of fields to use? For example, `bq_table_upload("project.dataset.table_name", df_name, fields=df_name)`. When you provide fields argument as a dataframe, [the table schema is generated from it](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/blob/feb1a9ab3019bdd96848acce81cdcfe6770696d6/R/bq-field.R#L86) and used in the [upload request](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery/blob/d12fabaa4cf6dfe0ea81c721fb0932abbc90c0e7/R/bq-perform.R#L130).